# Restoring Azure SQL Server to a previous point without replicas

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am reading some guides to see how to backup/restore a Microsoft Azure SQL Server database.

Searching Microsoft documentation, it seems that:

> Azure SQL Database has automated backups, so Azure Data Studio doesn't perform Azure SQL Database backup and restore. For more information, see Learn about automatic SQL Database backups.

After further reading, I see we can indeed restore a DB by creating a replica of it at a previous time point, but this costs ~80 euros if I read it correctly, as it basically creates a second instance of the db. Also, It seems to be able to go back in time only some limited time.

Is there a cost-less (without incurring additional cost to the existing costs) way to create a "permanent" off line copy of the database and restore it to an Azure SQL Database?

The first part of this question is  similar to [Is there a way to download the azure sql database managed backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396972/is-there-a-way-to-download-the-azure-sql-database-managed-backups) - though I am not asking if it's possible, and I do not care about any format of the backup, and do not want to download the Azure backups. I would be happy creating my own backup so I am pretty sure the answer to my question is that is possible even though that answer is probably impossible.

Comment: If you want to create a local backup of an Azure SQL Database, you can use DACPACs and BACPACs.

Comment: I connect to the db with Azure Data Studio (1.32.0), and it does not seem to give me the option to create a backup, possibly because I am connected to an azure server and not an msql server ??? Or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Have you installed the extension?

Comment: What's the actual objective? To restore to a point in time? Simply go into the Azure portal and do it in there. Azure Data Studio probably doesn't have a nice way for you to do this. https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20210730-PointInTimeRestoreOfAzureSqlDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a cost-less (without incurring additional cost to the
> existing costs) way to create a "permanent" off line copy of the
> database and restore it to an Azure SQL Database?

You would have to install an extension to use DACPAC and BACPAC features in Azure Data studio.

```
Name: SQL Server Dacpac
Id: microsoft.dacpac
Description: Manage data-tier applications
Version: 1.8.0
Publisher: Microsoft
```

[image]

Here is a simple way to export DB as Bacpac, you can similarly use the [Import Bacpac] Operation to restore.

I am Connected to Microsoft SQL Server, backing up a SQL DB. But you can do this connecting to on-premise SQL server too.

[image]

Comment: Note that dacapac is not practical for large data volumes (100's of Gb's)

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual objective?

You can restore an Azure SQL to a point in time. Go into the Azure portal and do it in there. (Azure Data Studio may not have a nice way for you to do this)

By offline do you mean an on-premises (non cloud) copy? again what is the objective? Is it disaster recovery? Your on premises copy is more likely to be lost than the Azure one.

You can also point in time restore to another Azure database. If your DB <2Gb then you can just retore to the basic edition which is 4.25 Euro a month. Or you can use the serverless option which is even cheaper

But you have to consider why you are doing this. Azure has a lot of redundancy already built in which makes these kinds of manual offline copies and processes unecessary.

Comment: Just checking my open answers, not sure why I wanted this at the time, its possible that I wanted to be able to provide one of the clients with a backup (here is your data, this is a physical copy you can keep etc.) I know reliability wise this might seem foolish, but... I am not sure what i end up doing, since its been a while, but it might be related to dbeaver, a local postgress and copying of all tables at the same time....